# How do I discover what social media the user has chosen?

Tags: ios, xamarin

How do I discover what social media the user has chosen, using Xamarin on iOS?

Look at my example below:

```
using (UIActivityViewController actController = new   UIActivityViewController(activityTypes, null))
{
  actController.ExcludedActivityTypes = new NSString[]
  { 
    UIActivityType.AddToReadingList,
    UIActivityType.AirDrop,
    UIActivityType.AssignToContact,
    UIActivityType.CopyToPasteboard,
    UIActivityType.Print,
    UIActivityType.SaveToCameraRoll
  };

  Version deviceVersion = new Version(UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion);

  if (deviceVersion >= iosVersion8) {
    actController.PopoverPresentationController.SourceView = buttonView;
  }

  PresentViewController(actController, true, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the completion handler like so:

```
actController.CompletionHandler += (NSString arg1, bool arg2) => {
    if (arg1.Equals(UIActivityType.PostToFacebook))
    {
        Console.Write ("YOU CHOOSE FACEBOOK!");
    }
};
```